# Is it ok to ask that answers relate only to specific geographic areas?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have noticed that answers to some some questions are hugely dependent on where the OP lives. Like questions related to for instance workplace, paternity leave and similar. But I have not seen anyone ask the answers to be from persons living in the same geographic area.

Is it ok for the OP to ask that only people in the same country or with the knowledge of the "rules" in said country answers? Or is it preferable that the OP specifically state where they are from and expect answers to be relevant to them and their situation in their geographical area?

Comment: You're free to ask but I'm free to ignore it. If my answer turns out not to be helpful the down votes will tell me.

Comment: @rene is that really true though? You answer may be relevant to many from the area on which your answer is about, but the OP may be from another area and for him/her the answer seems irrelevant.

Comment: In that case down vote, assuming the question clearly stated for which region answers should apply.

Comment: @Aidin you seem to be confusing two very different things. A question regarding a specific location is fine, and asking answers be relevant *to* that location is fine, but asking answerers *be in or from that location* is a very different thing.

Comment: @Cai Yes, you seem to be correct in me having confused the two. I just didn't quite understand why so many questions that are hugely dependent on where you live do not state for which area the answers are relevant, as if the OP assumes it is the same everywhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is perfectly OK to ask a question related *to* a specific location—relevant answers would then be specific to that location.

It is not OK to ask that *the people answering be in or from that specific location*. Anyone can answer a question, it's the content you should be focused on, not the people.

As well as it being OK to ask questions relevant to specific locations it's often important information needed to give an answer. If a question omits a specific location where it is important—ask for clarification in comments (that is what they're for after all).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not OK.

The person who asks can't, and shouldn't, decide who will answer.

Anyone can make a research, no matter where they live, and find better results than one living in the relevant place.

Stack Exchange is about *content*, not *people*. If one can come with good content, that's what matters. There was [even a bot](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/286271/152859) (using AI software) answering questions all by itself few years ago, and those were, and still are, totally legit answers.

Comment: I am totally with you on that. However, in many cases the OP never tells where he lives, then the ones answering have no way of knowing and they tend to only regard their own geographical area. As a result answeres from countries with more population have greater chance of getting more upvotes and hence might be hiding the relevant answer from the OP.

Comment: @Aidin if that logic holds then I'll start all my answers with: *I'm from China*, just to make sure I win the popularity vote ...

Comment: @Aidin there is a *very* big difference in a question relating to a specific location and specifically asking *answerers be in or from that location*.

Comment: Ok, so rather than to ask the answers to be from certain people it is better to state that the answers should be relevant to me who am from a certain place? Well, that makes sense. I am just confused in why so many questions don't state where they live so that they get relevant answers but instead assumes it is the same everywhere

Comment: @Aidin that's a totally different question. You can still edit your question here to reflect that, and I'll either edit or delete this answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If you edit the answer to match my edited question I can mark it as answered

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the question is on-topic for the specific Stack Exchange site it's perfectly okay to ask a question pertaining specifically to a certain geographic area or jurisdiction. This is quite common on The Workplace or law.SE sites for example.

But, why does it matter where the people providing answers are from? I don't care if you're from the U.S., Nigeria, are blue, worship Cthulhu, what education you may or may not have, or any other personal trait. As long as you can provide a good answer you can provide a good answer.

Judge content, not people.

Comment: You are a rude person, and this post should be flagged as such. (rude or abusive.)

Comment: The edit was made for a reason. The language used could use some cleaning up. Would you please undo your rollback? The argument you make is valid and not harmed by the deletion.

Comment: This would actually be a very good answer if it wasn't for the language...

Comment: @Cai true, but user chose to use that bad language on purpose so it's integral part of the answer.

Comment: Whoops, I seemed to have momentarily forgotten that this site *hates* jokes :-/ At any rate, I would not really consider a mention or "arse" rude, but YMMV. And making disagreement about content a personal attack @ShadowWizard ... Well, the less said about that the better...

Comment: Well, you removed half a paragraph without an edit summary @Bart, I saw that removed, went "hm", and just clicked "rollback' as it wasn't really obvious what the problem was ... But I'll remove my harmless little joke if it offends people so :-/

Comment: Thank you. I should have left a comment. Apologies.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - nope, sorry. The problem isn't that we don't like "jokes". But many aren't fond of vulgar jokes.