# Is this avatar appropriate or offensive?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture, inappropriate-content

I've been using [this avatar (may be NSFW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBh2q.jpg) at a different forum for years without a problem until today when a moderator on that site sent me a message that he had received complaints about the avatar and its resemblance to something other than a heart. Is this really over the top, and can I use it here?

Comment: Yes, on first view it appears to be NSFW. Doesn't matter if it really isn't.

Comment: "resemblance"?.......

Comment: "The forum/website is about deals and discounts" Are you asking about a moderator decision on *another* (as in not Stack Exchange) site?

Comment: @Cai No, just asking opinion. No decision has been made.

Comment: Then what is this deals and discounts website and what does it have to do with Stack Exchange? (Meta—where we are now—is *only* for questions relating to the SE network of sites, not general discussion/opinion)

Comment: i.e. if your asking if that avatar is appropriate *for Stack Exchange*, that is probably ok, but if you're asking for a general opinion (including its use elsewhere) that isn't really on-topic here.

Comment: It **is**, literally, a bare butt with tan lines surrounded by bubbles that form a heart shape. I don't think there's a "resemblance" there.

Comment: @cai I don't understand your replies. They seem to appear as bunch of replies when they  could have been just one. Also, when I ask for opinion here in SE, the question has to be related to SE? I can't perhaps ask question about how good is iPhone 7  ?

Comment: I don't believe that Stack Exchange has a site about deals and discounts. If you're talking about a non-SE site, I don't see how it has any bearing on the argument here. We don't set our standards based on what other sites allow.

Comment: We don't allow opinion questions on SE sites *generally*. So a question asking "how good the iPhone 7 is" would certainly be closed, even on the site it applies to, [apple.se]. No, you can't come to Meta Stack Exchange to ask questions about the web in general. We don't control the wider web, we only control Stack Exchange.

Comment: Apologies if I was unclear but yes, as I said, "*Meta—where we are now—is only for questions relating to the SE network of sites, not general discussion/opinion*" See [What is Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get an idea of what we expect, users who use Gravatar for their avatars can only use images rated G or PG. We don't allow adult-only avatars.

The way I'm seeing it, this avatar is NSFW and sexually explicit to the point where it is only appropriate for 17+ audiences. I would not consider it appropriate for a site with participation from 13+ teenagers and an audience that includes young children.

Comment: "For users who use Gravatar" ...what about those who don't?

Comment: The Gravatar standard is intended to represent what content is considered appropriate as avatars. It would logically follow that it extends to avatars hosted on stack.imgur.com.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your short yet comprehensive  reply.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly is considered "offensive" is a very cultural and personal matter. As a particularly liberally-minded Dutch person you need to try pretty damn hard to "offend" me by anything other hurling personal insults.

But what *you* or *I* think isn't really that important.

I've given the matter some thought as of late after a kerfuffle over what I thought was just a little joke [in this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286929/166789) (see the edit history). It wasn't even my joke, I lifted it from Planescape Torment.

Now, I personally *still* don't agree that it is particularly "offensive" or "vulgar", and I *still* think the reactions were overblown. But at the same time I could have *expected* that at least *some* people would have this opinion, and including this particular joke was probably not the best judgement in hindsight. It wasn't important at all for the gist of my answer and it was just a useless distraction.

In the same vein, I don't think your avatar is offensive at all. I never understood the whole hysteria about sex thing (it's like a dependency for the survival of the species), but perhaps that's just me.

However, hat doesn't really matter. We're not here to discus the finer points of what is and isn't offensive or vulgar. We're here to build a quality Q&A site with useful high-quality content. One of the great virtues of the Stack Exchange network is the *absence* of distractions and drama.

As a rule of thumb: if you *think* a reasonable number of people might find something offensive – whether you consider this reasonable or not – then using it probably isn't a great idea. It will just be a useless distraction and will contribute nothing.

Comment: In other words, "if you have to ask if something is offensive", it likely is.  :-)

Comment: @Ramhound I wouldn't word it like that because it sort of implies some objective standard of offensive – but it does describe the basic gist of my answer, yes.